# UIWebView won't load in Xcode6

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, xcode6

(Xcode 6.1, iOS 7.1, iPhone)

UIWebView will not load the page. YES, I have wired the webView (to the .h file)

Done this 1000 times... trying not to pull my hair out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Any ideas? I've noticed that UIWebViews seem to be a little flaky in Xcode 6.

Comment: I tested your code and it works. The only problem I had was to make it not work. Perhaps you could show more of your code? Or screenshots how you connect the web views etc?

Comment: Is that not being loaded not being display ?
Have tried this delegate method for web view "-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView"

Comment: It is loaded but not displayed correctly. Worked in the past. When updated my MacBook to OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) and XCode to 6.1 it stopped working. Changed nothing else.

Comment: Are you sure that the UIWebView is visible? Are the constraints set correctly?

Comment: If you set some background color do you see anything? In you webViewDidFinishLoad can you set a breakpoint a log [self.view recursiveDescription] to see the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 3):

**I checked your code but try it once Programatically,**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {    
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
        [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self.view addSubview:webview];
    }
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work unfortunately... It is since the update to XCode 6.1 that it does not work on an iOS 7.1 device.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your web view's storyboard constraints are properly set, you should in the viewDidLoad, set yourself as your web view's delegate

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

and the implement the following methods in your view controller. It will be called when your web view will try to access the web, so you can tell it that, Yes, it should start loading.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I did this. It also loads the content correctly as I check the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate and checked the inner contents of the webView. However, it is not displayed on the iPad's screen.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code as its working fine on my side. May be this solves your problem.

```
UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,       self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
[webview loadRequest:nsrequest1];
[self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code is working fine. The problem is not there, I'm sure. (also WebView is working fine in iOS8 SDK)
To debug issue, just implement `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` delegate method, and see where the error comes.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error loading webview: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Hope it will help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
```

.m

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://google.co.za";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not set below part in `info.plist`.So check it.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Let me know is it helps you.